# How to get the value from Private field into Protected field

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am not getting the right value of `flag` after setting it inside ButtonAdd_Click. The scenario is when I click on ButtonAdd, that the `protected void ButtonAdd_Click` calls the `private AddNewRowToGrid()` which sets the `flag=true` which is used by `protected void btn3_click`.

```
public partial class WebForm3 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    bool flag = false;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //MyCode
    }  
    private void AddNewRowToGrid()
    {
        flag = true;
    }
    protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddNewRowToGrid();
    }
    protected void btn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(flag == true)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Explain the flow of your program more clearly. Explain what value you have for `flag` at different points, and what value you want.

Comment: It's a field, its state is shared by the methods in the class.

Comment: I am making a installment package, it only works when i click add button . I have two buttons one is save and one is add the save button contains all the addition code and add button contains the flag= true, if a person does not want to make a installment then he does not click the add button that in save button the code in if(flag== true) does not execute .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is the fact that each button click is a new postback to the server that will create a **new instance** of your class to handle each request.

This means that setting the `flag` in between 2 postbacks, one when you click on the `ButtonAdd` button and one when you click on the `btn3_Click` button has no effect as you noticed yourself

The easiest solution is to store this `flag` in the `ViewState` (remark: be very careful about what you want to store in the `ViewState` as it will be send back and forth with each request)

either way if you change your code like this, then it'll do what you were expecting:

```
public partial class WebForm3: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //MyCode
    }

    private void AddNewRowToGrid()
    {
        Flag = true;
    }

    protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddNewRowToGrid();
    }

    protected void btn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Flag == true)
        {
        }
    }

    private bool Flag
    {
        get
        {
            bool? flag = ViewState["flag"] as bool?;
            return flag.HasValue ? flag.Value : false;
        }

        set
        {
            ViewState["flag"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am making a installment package, it only works when i click add button . I have two buttons one is save and one is add the save button contains all the addition code and add button contains the flag= true, if a person does not want to make a installment then he does not click the add button that in save button the code in if(flag== true) does not execute